# How to use Try/Catch to prevent String input where an Int is needed

Tags: java, try-catch

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package freetime;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Andy
*/
public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput=0,notInt=0,newInput=0;
    System.out.println("Enter a integer number");
    while (notInt == 0){
        try {
            newInput=scan.nextInt();
            userInput=newInput;
            if (userInput != newInput){
                notInt=0;
            }
            if (userInput == newInput){
                notInt=1;
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("That is not an integer, please try again." );
        }
    }
    System.out.println(userInput);

 }
}
```

I am trying to prevent a string input and allow the user to re input as an int. i cannot seem to get it to work properly, i also did this without the while loop. I think my understanding of how the Try Mismatch functions work is causing some issues.

Thanks for the help.

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput=0,notInt=0,newInput=0;
    boolean runL=true;
    while (runL){
        System.out.println("Enter a integer number");
        if (scan.hasNextInt()){
           userInput=scan.nextInt();
           runL=false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("That is not an integer, please try again.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(userInput);
```

So i changed the code to this but I am still running into the loop continuing to go after something other than an int is entered. What am i doing wrong?

```
    int userInput=0,notInt=0,newInput=0;
    boolean runL=true;
    while (runL){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a integer number");
        if (scan.hasNextInt()){
           userInput=scan.nextInt();
           runL=false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("That is not an integer, please try again.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(userInput);
```

I've found the problem, I needed to create the scanner object inside of the While loop. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you seen the `hasNextInt` method? (I'd also strongly encourage you to use the `boolean` type for `true`/`false` values, rather than having an `int` with a value of 0 or 1...)

Comment: if conditions has no use in your code , comparison with itself and use above suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think my understanding of how the Try Mismatch functions work is causing some issues.

You are probably right there ...

When I remove some of the "strange" code from your `try` / `catch` statement it looks like this:

```
    try {
        newInput = scan.nextInt();
        // do stuff
    } catch (InputMismatchException e){
        // do other stuff
    }
```

Here's what that actually means:

1. Call `scan.nextInt()`
2. If the call succeeds (i.e. it doesn't throw an exception), then:

   1. assign the result to `newInput`
   2. "do stuff"
3. If the call failed, AND it threw a `InputMismatchException`, then:

   1. "do other stuff"

So, based on that, you don't need to do anything in "do stuff" to test if you just got a valid input.  You *know* that is the case.

And likewise, any stuff that needs to be do in the case where you *didn't* get a valid input should be in "do other stuff".

---

Having said that, Jon Skeet's suggestion to look at the `hashNextInt` method is spot on.  If you use that the right way, you won't get an exception at all.  The code will be much simpler.

And Jon is also correct that you should be using the `boolean` type for your true / false logic.  (That is what the type is intended for!)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt(input)` in try block.
If input is not an int, then it will throw an exception and catch the exception in `catch{} block`.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop should look like this:

```
while (notInt == 0){
    try {
        newInput=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        userInput=newInput;
        notInt=1;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("That is not an integer, please try again." );
    }
}
```

Your code doesn't work because when a `InputMismatchException` is thrown, the token that causes the exception isn't actually read. So the loop is reading the same thing every iteration.

`nextLine` however, almost always reads the whole line as a string (except when there's no line). You put the string that is read into `Integer.parseInt` to turn it into an `int`. If it can't be turned into an `int`, a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

However, you should not use exceptions as a way of validating inputs because it's slow. You can try this approach with regex:

```
while (notInt == 0){
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    if (p.matcher(line).matches()) {
        userInput = Integer.parseInt(line);
        notInt = 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do the validation using a regex (reliably).  There are valid integers that match that pattern that will still throw an exception.  (Hint: 2^31 - 1 is not a power of 10 ......)

Comment: @StephenC I see. It'll crash if the user enters a number that's more than the maximum value of integer, won't it? If such a large input makes sense in the context, OP should probably use a long or `BigInteger`, not an `int`.

Comment: Actually, I think that you DON'T see.  The real solution is to use `hasNextInt()` rather than some dodgy pattern matching.